# Remove parenthesis and everything in between using Apex?

Tags: apex

I have strings inside parenthesis that appears at the end of many opportunity names.  For example, "ABC Opportunity (ABC)".

I want to completely remove/strip these off **for visually display purposes** using Apex, but not not actually change the name stored on the Account record in salesforce.   For example, a string of "ABC Opportunity (ABC)" would end up displaying as "ABC Opportunity".

```
String returnString;
String oppName = 'ABC Opportunity (ABC)';
String returnString = // strip or string replacement 

System.debug('----- debug >>> ' + returnString);

// should return only ABC Opportunity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work.

```
String oppName = 'ABC Opportunity (ABC)';
String returnString = oppName.replaceAll('\\(.*\\)', '');

System.debug('----- debug >>> ' + returnString);
```

This regex matches all `(` and `)` and replaces with a blank string.

Comment: This would just replace the parenthesis, not the content inside them. To do what you're suggesting, you'd need something like `'\\(.*\\)`

Comment: Oh just missed that part. Didnt read the question properly. Thanks